# Java Regex Expression isn't working for File Validation

Tags: java, regex, file

I'm trying to validate a filepath a user has entered through a swing box. They click on the location where they want the file and then they add the name of the file by themselves. So they need to make sure it is in the format such as "C:/files/documents/hello.txt  and they need to specify the file type at the end so i can create a new file to write to. The isFile method doesn't seem to satisfy this as the file has to exist, so i'm trying to use regex now with an if statement to validate the file path .

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
            String fileName = "C:/users/furquan/hello.txt";
            File zerina = new File (fileName);
            //FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream (zerina);
            String regex = "\\^(?:[\w]\:|\\\)(\\\[a-z_\-\s0-9\.]+)+\\\.(txt|gif|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx)$";
            System.out.println (fileName.matches(regex));
    }
}
```

I know you need to add more slashes in java regex because of the escape sequence but i can't get it to work

Comment: Why do you want to use a regexp? Couldn't you just check, whether a file at that location can be created?

Comment: your example won't even compile

Comment: Forget about checking the *path* yourself. This can be done better via `File`. Just check if the last part of the path, i.e. the filename, ends with the right characters, and that the full path does not refer to a directory, which you can't overwrite as a file.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`java.nio.file.Path`](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/path.html). (you don't need `Regex`s)

for example :

```
// imports
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;


Path path = Paths.get("C:/users/furquan/hello.txt");
Path parent = path.getParent();
if (Files.exists(parent) && path.getFileName().endsWith(".txt")) {
    // your code goes here
}
```

**EDIT** :

Also, if you want to validate file names :

```
static final Pattern FILE_NAME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("([\\w\\d\\s\\-\\.])+\\.(txt|gif|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx)");

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "C:/users/furquan/hello.txt";
    System.out.println(createFile(s));
}

static boolean createFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
    if (Files.exists(path)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (FILE_NAME_PATTERN.matcher(path.getFileName().toString()).matches()) {
        Path parent = path.getParent();
        if (!Files.exists(parent)) {
            Files.createDirectories(parent);
        }
        Files.createFile(path);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have way too much escaping and unnecessary stuff in your regex. None of the characters you're dealing with need escaping, and in fact escaping them breaks your regex.

Try this:

```
String regex = "(?i)[A-Z]:[\\\\\\w\\s.-]+)\\.(txt|gif|pdf|docx|doc|xlsx|xls)";
```

Since `matches()` must match the *whole* string, `^` and `$` are *implied*, so leave them out.

Comment: it still comes up with an invalid escape sequence

Comment: Check you have the right number of backslashes - try copy-pasting